# Implementing the factory design pattern using metaclasses

Tags: python, factory, metaclass

I found a lot of links on metaclasses, and most of them mention that they are useful for implementing factory methods. Can you show me an example of using metaclasses to implement the design pattern?

Comment: is the accepted answer satisfying ? I was kind of looking for something a bit more detailled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd love to hear people's comments on this, but I think this is an example of what you want to do

```
class FactoryMetaclassObject(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        """__init__ will happen when the metaclass is constructed: 
        the class object itself (not the instance of the class)"""
        pass

    def __call__(*args, **kw):
        """
        __call__ will happen when an instance of the class (NOT metaclass)
        is instantiated. For example, We can add instance methods here and they will
        be added to the instance of our class and NOT as a class method
        (aka: a method applied to our instance of object).

        Or, if this metaclass is used as a factory, we can return a whole different
        classes' instance

        """
        return "hello world!"

class FactorWorker(object):
  __metaclass__ = FactoryMetaclassObject

f = FactorWorker()
print f.__class__
```

The result you will see is: type 'str'

Comment: can you add a little "factoriness" to the example, i.e some customization applied to the created objects?

Answer (score 2):

You can find some helpful examples at [wikibooks/python](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/MetaClasses), [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20180209225930/http://onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2003/04/17/metaclasses.html) and [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120929051646/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-pymeta/index.html)

Comment: those are exactly the links I stumbled on. I couldn't find a concrete example of a factory (though all of them mention it) in any of them...

Comment: Your O'Reilly and IBM links are stale. (Not surprising after a decade!) Please consider refreshing them and posting some of the contents.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need. You can [override a class's `__new__()` method](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.1/descrintro/#__new__) in order to return a completely different object type.

Comment: I don't think you can with metaclasses... (maybe you can - if so let me know and I will have learned something :) )

Comment: @RyanWilcox: `__new__()` can return anything.